# Finding $(this) after a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, html

So here's my problem: I'm using a function and I need the function to be specific to each tr with the class "middleone". It's supposed to change the insides of a div inside of the the tr with the class "middleone". But it's not working!

I know the recursive portion of it is working, and the "navigation" should be spot on, because even when i'm using just $(this) it doesn't do anything. When using document.getElementById it works fine but of course that only targets the first div and the full version of the code has to "Go here, pull from here, put it here, go to the next area, pull from here.. etc" Here's the testing code.

```
$('.middleone').each(function() {
    var tripleeagain = $(this).find('div')
    tripleeagain.innerHTML = "$";
});
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post the HTML and (possibly) mock this up in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tripleeagain` is a jquery object collection upon which you should use `html()` instead of `innerHTML`

Basically you could just write:

```
 $('.middleone').find('div').html("$");
```

If you are doing specific stuff inside the loop then:

```
  $('.middleone').each(function() {
     //Some specific logic
      var tripleeagain = $(this).find('div').html("$");

  });
```

Comment: This fixed it. Didn't even think of that. Thanks, you're awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to access native API from a jQuery object.

```
var tripleeagain = $(this).find('div');// this will return a jQuery object
```

So you should use the jQuery API for setting the html contents

```
tripleeagain.html("$");
```

[jQuery html <sup>API documentaion</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/)